# No me llega la respuesta desde una petición POST

Tags: android, nodejs, express, android-volley

Al hacer una petición POST desde Android a un servidor Node con los enpoints hechos en Express, no sé porqué no me llega el JSON de contestación o no sé si el onResponse es el método que tengo que utilizar para leer la respuesta en los POST, a ver si me podeis ayudar.

Este es mi trozo de código que hace la petición desde Android

```
       request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(params),
               new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                       try {
                           //Parseamos el JSON de respuesta
                           Boolean error = response.getBoolean("Error");
                           if (error) {
                               falloEnvio += "--------------------------\n";
                               falloEnvio += response.getString("message");
                               falloEnvio += "\n--------------------------\n\n";
                           } else {
                               JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject("message");
                               idTicket[0] = json.getString("_id");
                           }
                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }
               }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
               Log.e("Volley", "Error !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
               System.out.println(error);
           }
       });
       queue.add(request);
```

y esta es la respuesta que manda el endpoint

```
    Ticket.TicketCaja.find({ "Tipo": strings.TIPOC, 'Fecha': new Date(hoy.getFullYear(), hoy.getMonth(), hoy.getDate()) }, function(err,doc){           if(doc==""){    //Si no hay ningun ticket con fecha de hoy
            ticketCaja.save(function(err, ticket){
                if(err){
                    funciones.log(strings.POSTERR + strings.TIPOC.toLowerCase());
                    res.json({"error" : true,"message" : strings.POSTERR.toUpperCase() + strings.TIPOC});
                }
                else{
                    funciones.log(strings.LOGPOST + strings.TIPOC);
                    res.json({"error" : false,"message" : ticket});
                }
            });             }           else{
            funciones.log(strings.POSTEXISTS + strings.TIPOC.toLowerCase())
            res.json({"error" : true,"message" : strings.POSTEXISTS.toUpperCase() + strings.TIPOC});            }       });
```

Sé que llega al endpoint ya que el valor que mando me lo almacena en la base de datos.

Comment: Hola Diego, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: ¿Qué mostraría un `Log` de `response` dentro del método `onResponse`?  Ten en cuenta que estás buscando la clave `Error` dentro del JSON: `Boolean error = response.getBoolean("Error");`, pero en la respuesta la envías en minúscula: `error`... no estoy seguro si las claves de los objetos JSON son *case-sensitive*, de todos modos, hay escribir un código *coherente*, si es minúscula, minúscula.

Comment: El problema es que no llega a entrar nunca en el método onResponse. He puesto trazas de ejecución y no llegan nunca @A.Cedano

Comment: ¿Estás verificando los Log correctamente? Si no entra en `onResponse` entrará entonces en la parte de error.. ¿qué error imprime?

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que estén concedidos los permisos de internet?
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> ` Un saludo!

Comment: Que error imprime entonces en onErrorResponse? @DiegoGalvez si no entra en  onResponse o en onErrorResponse entonces no estarías  llamando la petición.

Answer (score 0):

He usado ambas tecnologías y tuve una situación de que si mandas un 404, que bien puede manejarse como un ejemplo que no encuentres resultados en la busqueda, pues volley lo toma como error. Puede ser que estes usando respuestas con res.json() intenta `res.status(200).json({name: data})`
Si me preguntas lo mejor que te recomiendo es el uso de Retrofit pero si sigues decidido a usar Volley te recomindo leas este articulo que provee un medio de uso de Volley super simplificado y con una genial eficiencia
https://medium.com/@nishinraj/simplifying-volley-requests-kotlin-development-1bb87c3fb6f8